# Using GeorgianCalendar inside groovy in nifi executescript processor

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

Is it possible to use  java.util.GeorgianCalendar in groovy and how can i implements it in executescript processor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whole java stack.

To use it just start your script with `import java.util.GeorgianCalendar`

90% that works in java - works in groovy.